# sql jdbc query - фильтрация

Tags: sql, jdbc

Я хочу вернуть отфильтрованные по LocalDateTime из параметров данные из БД , как правильно составить запрос?

```
@Override
    public List<Meal> getBetweenHalfOpen(LocalDateTime startDateTime, LocalDateTime endDateTime, int userId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM meals WHERE date_time BETWEEN date_time AND date_time=? AND date_time=? " +
                "ORDER BY user_id=?, date_time DESC",  ROW_MAPPER, startDateTime, endDateTime, userId);
    }
```

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: boolean = timestamp without time zone
  Подсказка: Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
  Позиция: 68
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2657)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2347)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:337)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:484)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:404)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:162)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    ru.javawebinar.topjava.repository.jdbc.JdbcMealRepository.getBetweenHalfOpen(JdbcMealRepository.java:75)
    ru.javawebinar.topjava.service.MealService.getBetweenInclusive(MealService.java:33)
    ru.javawebinar.topjava.web.meal.MealRestController.getBetween(MealRestController.java:73)
    ru.javawebinar.topjava.web.MealServlet.doGet(MealServlet.java:79)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM meals WHERE date_time BETWEEN ? AND ? AND user_id=? ORDER BY date_time DESC"`

Comment: супер! спасибо вам